# Remove Business Solution Provider (BSP) from Facebook (WhatsApp)

Tags: facebook, twilio, whatsapp, facebook-business-manager

I'm trying to connect directly to WhatsApp API.
I'm already connected using a business solution provider (twilio) but I can't find how to remove it.
I couldn't find any sign for Twilio in my business settings and when I'm trying to use my own number, I have this message.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you go back to Business Manager where you see all the WhatsApp Accounts > click on your WABA (WhatsApp Business Account) > Partners tab > click the delete button to remove sharing your account with the BSP.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, I don't see my BSP in the Partners tab

Comment: This might disconnect you phone numbers: See https://www.facebook.com/business/help/861444384718867